# Quartz.Net - Job does not wait to finish previous execution while running on multiple instances

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, quartz.net

I have an issue while running Quartz.Net job across multiple instances. I want to be sure that my job that is running on one instance is finished before another one is triggered on the second instance.

I have tried using `[DisallowConcurrentExecution]` annotation, but it only prevents jobs from running at the same time accross instances.

Here is my Quartz configuration:

```
        NameValueCollection properties = new NameValueCollection();

        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "TestScheduler";
        properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "instance_one";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "true";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_";
        properties["quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz";

        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = postgresConnectionString;
        properties["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "Npgsql";

        services.AddQuartz(q =>
        {
            q.Properties.Add(properties);
            q.UseDefaultThreadPool(x => x.MaxConcurrency = 5);
            q.UsePersistentStore(x =>
            {
                x.UsePostgres(Configuration.GetConnectionString("QuartzDatabase"));
                x.UseClustering(t =>
                {
                    t.CheckinInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                    t.CheckinMisfireThreshold = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                });
                x.UseJsonSerializer();
            });


            q.AddJob<HelloJob>(x => x.WithIdentity("job1", "group1").StoreDurably(true));
            q.AddTrigger(x => x
                    .ForJob("job1", "group1")
                    .WithIdentity("hellojob-trigger")
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(y =>
                    {
                        y.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever();
                        y.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires();
                    })
            );
        });
```

And here is my job:

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class HelloJob : IJob
{
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        LogData();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    void LogData()
    {
        Log.Information("Log test {@date}", DateTime.Now);
        Thread.Sleep(9000);
    }
}
```

Here are the logs from the first instance:

```
[20:45:30 INF] Log test 04/28/2022 20:45:30
[20:45:39 INF] Log test 04/28/2022 20:45:39
[20:45:48 INF] Log test 04/28/2022 20:45:48
```

And here are the logs from the second instance:

```
[20:44:36 INF] Log test 04/28/2022 20:44:36
[20:44:45 INF] Log test 04/28/2022 20:44:45
[20:44:54 INF] Log test 04/28/2022 20:44:54
```